# Prestashop api update resource error: Id is required when modifying a resource

Tags: xml, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

**Background:**

I am attempting to update the `shipping_number` of a an order resource, however, all combinations I have tried seem to be failing.

Currently using the `Prestashop 1.7.8.7` version (the latest as of writing this post).

I am trying to update the resource via the **rest api** that is available after enabling the WebService feature in my PrestaShop store. All of the fetch requests work without any problem...

Initially, the api calls were hooked up to use `JSON` format instead of the default `XML` format. However, after learning that the PUT requests only accept XML inputs, I updated this but I'm still getting an unsuccessful response.

Currently trying to get this work in `Postman` before I attempt to replicate in the codebase .

**Steps to reproduce in Postman:**

As per the Prestashop docs for updating a resource:
https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/webservice/getting-started/#update-a-resource

1. Fetch order by id: `[GET:] /api/orders/1?display=full`
2. Copy response from the fetch
3. Paste response into request body
4. Change value of the `shipping_method` node to something new/different
5. Update order: `[PUT:] /api/orders/1`

[image]

I have also enabled more detailed error response messages by adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` into the `config/config.inc.php` file. This is show in the additional message in the response below.

**Update response:**

```
Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /webservice/dispatcher.php on line 40

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 90,
            "message": "id is required when modifying a resource"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Other things attempted:**

Some of these attempts result in slightly different error messages (500 Internal Server Error etc.), but still fail nonetheless!

1. Changing the http method to a `POST` or `PATCH`
2. Updating the resource endpoint to point to `/orders` instead of `/orders/1` (the specific order I'm trying to update)
3. Changing the content type to `text` instead of `xml`
4. Various different xml strucutres in the request body (see below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <orders>
        <order>
            ...
        </order>
    </orders>
</prestashop>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <order>
        ...
    </order>
</prestashop>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
    ...
</order>
```

The only examples I can find online all look to be using the dedicated Prestashop WebServivce library which provides them with a dedicated client and allows them to call an `edit()` function, so haven't been of much help! Note: Using this library is also not an option on the basis my app is written in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure to POST the whole XML in a single line.

I remember having a similar problem due unrecognized / wrong carriage returns in request.